# how to resolve java.net.SocketEcxeption:failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 8080) in Genymotion

Tags: java, android, mysql, genymotion

I am building an android application that connect to MySQL for get and post some data to the server ,the application works fine when i am using android studio emulator ,but when i tried to use ***Genymotion*** emulator i have this problem 
`java.net.SocketEcxeption:failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 8080)
isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)`

Comment: Please post the exact exception and stack trace. Not a mangled misspelt version of part of it.

Comment: there is not any exception or error                                                                  com.example.ahmad.lasttry D/Volley﹕ [1] Request.finish: 7574 ms: [ ] http://10.0.2.2/android_login_api/login.php 0x1e7db229 NORMAL 1

Comment: No exception apart from what you misspelt, you mean?

Answer (score -2):

to resolve the question you should to change the address that you were using to connect from 
"http://10.0.2.2/android_login_api/login.php"
and replace it with the address 
"http://10.0.3.2/android_login_api/login.php"